# Selenium C# Chromedriver download file on TeamCity

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, teamcity, selenoid

I am automating downloading and then reading a pdf through ITextSharp. This works perfectly when run locally, no issues. When run in CI is where issues occur, I believe the file is not downloading. The way I am executing the download is by navigating to the download url (`Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(PdfDlUrl)`) which I believe is working otherwise an error would prompt and fail the test there. Instead, the error is no file is at that location. Logging onto our build agent to check, I can confirm there is nothing downloaded / no file.

What I have for my chromeDriver options are:

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("disable-popup-blocking");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("enable-devtools-experiments");   
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Pdf.GetDefaultPdfDlPath());
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", false);
```

(note the pdf url is set to desktop via `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);`) Is it possible I missed something? We use Selenoid so I'm concerned there may be something up with the chromedriver we have there.

Comment: More than likely you aren't going to gain access to this folder on the server via a url, it probably expects some kind of query string parameter value to be passed or something else entirely for the server to serve up this file to a user.

Comment: Could be because of missing authentication in URL. Try to use URL like: `https://username:password@teamcity.example.com/path/to/pdf/example.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  My project was building into a service which I had installed on a virtual machine.   The issue was that I had not setup the service with sufficient permissions to access the c: drive and had to set it to run as myself login rather than just the defaults.